# Map Routing MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

Maybe my question is very easy to respond, but I am new in MVC3.

I have these possible routes in my MVC3 Web project:

- /brands/brandID
- /brands/{action}/{parameters}

where brands is my controller and brandID is a specific parameter that receives my Index action. Also, my brands controller has more actions and I need to define in the Global.asax the correct map routes to make it work.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

Comment: Inorder to pass brandID you need a controller action. Ex: `/brands/Index/1`

Comment: Yes, Index recives the brandID parameter. I've tried to define these map routes:             routes.MapRoute(
                "Brands",
                "brands/{action}/{parameters}",
                new { controller = "Brands", action = "Index", parameters = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Brands2",
                "brands/{*path}",
                new { controller = "Brands", action = "Index" }
            ); but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example in the [Custom Routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) (modified for your case).

Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "BrandDetails",
    "Brands/{brandID}",
    new { controller = "Brands", action = "Details" },
    new { brandID = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

BrandsController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Details(int brandID)
{
    return this.View(brandID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, ok, I have the brands controller with some actions: ie. /Brands/GetBrands/filter. And, I have the Brands/Index/BrandID action where BrandID is an identifier of the brand (it's variable). With your first route ("Brands") the Details action is always reciving the request, even for the GetBrands requests... So, still with my problem

Comment: Great, the only point here is that brandID is an string, but changing the regular expression, I think these can work. Thank you very much!!